# How to edit/update yaml file with user input in python without changing the format

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

Sample Yaml:

```
ver: v1
metadata:
    name: apisec
data:
    user: abc
    apikey: ''
---
ver: v1
metadata:
    name: dbsec
data:
    user: abc
    seckey: ''
---
```

I want to change the value of apikey and seckey with userinput.

what I have tried:

```
apikey = input('Enter ApiKey:)
SecKey= input('Enter SecKey:)

with open ('test.yaml', 'w+') as f:
    data = yaml.load_all(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
    for i, value in enumerate(data):
        if i == 0:
            value['data']['apikey'] = apikey
        if i == 1:
            value['data']['apikey'] = seckey

    with open ('test.yaml', 'w+') as yaml_file:
        yaml_file.write(yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False))
```

This does not work, How can I edit/update yaml file without changing the yaml format?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `list(data)` to convert the generator object to a `list` first. That way, you can then update list as normal:

```py
import yaml

yaml_data = """
ver: v1
metadata:
    name: apisec
data:
    user: abc
    apikey: ''
---
ver: v1
metadata:
    name: dbsec
data:
    user: abc
    seckey: ''
---
"""

apikey = 'A'
seckey= 'S'

data = list(yaml.load_all(yaml_data.rstrip('-\n'), yaml.SafeLoader))

# for i, value in enumerate(data):
#     if i == 0:
#         value['data']['apikey'] = apikey
#     if i == 1:
#         value['data']['apikey'] = SecKey

data[0]['data']['apikey'] = apikey
data[1]['data']['seckey'] = seckey

# print(data)
print(yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False))
```

Result:

```
- ver: v1
  metadata:
    name: apisec
  data:
    user: abc
    apikey: A
- ver: v1
  metadata:
    name: dbsec
  data:
    user: abc
    seckey: S
```